# DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges when EF is another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have separated my solution in separate projects, a DAL project with entity framework and an ASP.NET MVC project.

I want to use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, but I don't know where to put it to make it work.

I've tried to put it in the web.config of the MVC project and the app.config of the DAL project (both by making use of the context element), I've tried putting it in the global.asax (`Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BreakAwayContext>());`), I've tried a custom initialization class, but none of these seem to work.

If possible, I don't want to make use of migrations. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a class to implement [CreateDatabaseIfNotExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221(v=vs.113).aspx) and call [Database.SetInitializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.113).aspx) function in Application_Start().

-DbInitializer

```
public class MyDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        //Data initializing...
    }
}
```

-Application_Start

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{ 
   Database.SetInitializer(new MyDbInitializer());
}
```

The database will be create when running the application.

And if you would like to do a automatic migration of database, use [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx) class

```
public class Configuration :  DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;            
    }
```

}

-Application_Start

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext,Configuration>());
```

Howerver, I recomand that using migraion commands will be more flexible. See this walkthru: [Overview of Entity Framework Code First Migrations with example](http://www.dotnetspan.com/2015/03/code-first-migrations-in-Entity-framework-example.html), by Bhavik Patel.

Comment: I just tried this solution, and it seems to work, I don't get an error stating that the model backing the database has changed, but the model changes have not been picked up. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Garth Marenghi, please use [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx) instead and I updated the answer. Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 1):

I guess by 'database initialization' you actually mean 'updating the database schema'.

1. Set the EfRepository as start up project of the solution
2. Open the Package manager console Choose EfRepository as default project
3. Run the following commands:

   Enable-Migrations -ConnectionStringName "EfDataRepository"

   Add-Migration Initial -ConnectionStringName "EfDataRepository"

   Update-Database -ConnectionStringName "EfDataRepository" -Script -SourceMigration:0

This will give you a .sql script. Execute it against your database (and usually store it as part of the solution - either Create.sql or some kind of a migration .sql, depends on whether you already have a schema or you are creating it from scratch).

Of course, replace `EfDataRepository` with the data connection name from your .config file.

Comment: Well, what I meant was that I wanted to do something like `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DbContext>());` since I'm just working on something small at the moment. From what I gather, is that you are suggesting using migrations. Is this the only option when separating projects? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you always generate .sql scripts out of your Entities project and 'manually' update/create the database from them. It's a migration, yes. The first time you generate a script (Create.sql, as I call it) is also a migration.